# Why does the Android overview screen still show an app after the onDestroy() method has been called?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I thought `onDestroy()` was supposed to remove all traces of the app from memory. If this is the case, then why do you still see an app in the task manager after pressing the back button (which calls `onDestroy()`)?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought onDestroy() was supposed to remove all traces of the app from memory

No. `onDestroy()` is a lifecycle callback that you can optionally override to do some cleanup in your activity or service.

> then why do you still see an app in the task manager after pressing the back button (which calls onDestroy() )?

Because your activity was part of a recent task.